# Django cannot find template, app is in installed_apps and backend DjangoTemplates is enabled

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

Inside of a page in my templates folder, I tried using an include statement in a for loop, like so:

```
        {% for model_othermodel in model.othermodels.all%}
        {% include othermodels.html with othermodel=model_othermodel %}
        {%endfor%}
```

At first, I had the issue that it complained there was no key/value being sent to the other template, which was that othermodel=model_othermodel looked like other_model = model_othermodel.
However, after that, I had the issue that it could not find the included html file (the file name is correct), for which the error problem would show me the base.html file that each page extends.

(I will be using django_app to refer to the app folder)

I got the error message:
In template path\root\django_app\templates\base.html, error at line 0
No template names provided

My base.html file is just a file for bootstrap that every other html file extends.

My project structure looks like this:
root/django_app
root/django_project
root/django_app/templates

I tried adding the template path directly to 'DIRS' in TEMPLATES, such as so:
`DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, django_app/templates/)]`
with variations such as django_app/templates, /templates/, /templates, etc.

After that, I heard a suggestion to reorder my INSTALLED_APPS list, which is currently:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'django_app',
]
```

to

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
]
```

But this only gave me errors for my admin and registering models, and that post didn't seem to have any basis - when I researched the order in installed apps, I found that local apps (in this case, django_app) should come after django apps.

It also seems like django did not look through the app templates at all:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    This engine did not provide a list of tried templates.
```

We could just use templating to write the other_model html that I want inside of that for loop, but it would also mean that the front-end developer lacks a very convenient templating tool. I know for sure that django can find the module, as it gives me an error if "django_app" is mispelled in anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
{% include 'othermodels.html' with othermodel="model_othermodel" %}
```